# how can I use PCA in video processing

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, video-processing

I'm a beginner in video processing. I want to extract features out of the frames, for the first step I applied a descriptor on each frame which resulting in 1*500 feature vector. My question is how should I perform PCA on My dataset? 
should I perform PCA on each feature vector that is resulted by performing PCA on each frame?

Comment: Introduction to Principal Component Analysis (PCA)                                          http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d1/dee/tutorial_introduction_to_pca.html#gsc.tab=0

Answer (score -1):

I don't think PCA on features on each frame is a rational idea.

In fact, if you are using descriptors, you can try [**Bag-of-words**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model_in_computer_vision), which is widely used in computer vision community. Once your get the historgram from Bag-of-word, it is common to perform PCA on those histograms.

So this is how it flows:

> Video --> raw descriptor --> historgram --> PCA --> final feature

Comment: thank you for your answer. what are the other important tricks and manners for feature extraction and feature selection and which of them is more efficient?

Comment: Glad that can help. First, chi-square kernel is widely used to handle raw (not projected) histogram features. Like chi-square kernel SVM, or chi-square kernel PCA. Second, there are many handcrafted feature selectors you can use. [This](http://serre-lab.clps.brown.edu/resource/hmdb-a-large-human-motion-database/#Evaluation) is a video dataset and it lists major feature descriptors on video. Third, many deep learning-based method, like 2-stream network, can produce promising features. However you have to implement yourself since not public network parameter is not available to my best knowledge

Comment: I'm working on a dataset that used two cameras for observation.I extracted features of the frames by a descriptor and it has resulted in a (1*500) dimensional vector.


Now for reducing dimensions I want to use PCA  and I don't know how to apply it on my data. 

Should I apply PCA on each couple of frames that was recorded in same time or should I apply PCA on all frames of each camera separately?